# Yarn Capacity Scheduler: Share resource between users and queues

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I am having some trouble settings the following scheduler queues params:

have 2 queue Dev and Prod

- Root 100%

  - Dev 30%
  - Prod 70%

(if only one used it should act as 100% of cluster)

Each queue is used by multiple users and resources should be shared equally, but when only one user exists(in each queue) it should use the entire capacity of the queue. And if the user alone in the cluster it should use 100% of the cluster in case of second user join, the scheduler should share the available resources

what i have now, example flow:

1. cluster is free of jobs
2. user A submit job at queue Dev. (it now uses 100% of the cluster)
3. user B submit job at queue Dev (it hangs in accepted and wait to the first job to finish)

What i want:

In this case because the second job is in the same queue each should receive 50% of the queue which is 100% of the cluster.

then if another job enters to Prod queue ( 2 jobs on Prod will share 70% (35% each) and one job on Dev will have 30% )

in another case if the job enters to the other queue (1 each total), the capacity should be 30,70

based on Apache Ambari

Version 2.6.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job B will have to wait for job A to complete. As far as I know, there’s no way to redistributed the load on the same YARN queue.

The production jobs will be prioritized if you have enabled preemption (https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/preemption.html) and should take indeed 70% of the resources. As for the dev queue, first in, first serve..

Comment: yarn have preemption that allow this capability, but i cant make it to work https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/preemption.html

Comment: preemption works between queues but not inside the same queue

Comment: there is no other way i can share resorces between multiple users on the same queue ?

Comment: well, best practices. On HIVE/TEZ, you can limit the number of jobs being triggered with parameters `tez.grouping.split-count`and `hive.exec.reducers.max`

Comment: We are based on yarn\spark, i dont want to go for another adventure and integration, ill preffer to make it work, ill try to make queue for eatch user

Comment: I did not ask to change anything. With Spark, you specify how many workers you need so what's the problem here? Somehow you need a production plan for your  jobs

Comment: FYI - you'd run into the same issues with Fair Scheduler.  There is no way of preempting within a queue.  Both schedulers will use any spare capacity on the cluster unless you explicitly cap resources.  You can move a job to a new queue but this is only a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

as Harold said

> there’s no way to redistributed the load on the same YARN queue

But if you make **sub queues** inside for each user it can work,but you have to manage it for each user, (we are small company and have few users so it manageable)

- Root 100%
- Prod 70%

  - user1 25% (25 of the 70)
  - user2 25% (25 of the 70)
  - user3 25% (25 of the 70)
  - user4 25% (25 of the 70)

I configured this scenario on our grid, but still looking for a better approach